# Generate comboboxes depending on number inserted in first combobox

Tags: excel, combobox, logic, vba

I'm doing an userform where in one of the fields (lets say its combobox1) the user is asked for the number of failures, and for each failure he has to put the type of failure, number of part and in another field the type of rework (3 fields to fill for each failure). And what I would like to know if that if it's possible to generate comboboxes depending on the number of failures made. For example: if the user puts 3 in the field of failures, 9 comboboxes should appear and so on.

I also think that maybe another way would be to have the standards 3 comboboxes and clear the fields each time the user press a button and a counter appears indicating which failure description he is filling, but I would also like to know how this could integrate into the whole userform, which already has a "submit" button.

Maybe there could be another reasoning for this, and I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really have much experience using dynamically created tabstrips, but they may be helpful with creating the layout you're describing. I would recommended in the base userform, include a tabstrip with a single tab and the 3 comboboxes/textboxes that are needed for a single failure. (You could keep it invisible until after "combobox1" has a value, if desired) Then use the number from the combobox to dynamically create the additional tabs on the tabstrip:

```
Private Sub ComboBox_Change()
    'To remove previous tabs if combobox changed
    For i = 1 To TabStrip1.Tabs.Count - 1
        TabStrip1.Tabs.Remove(i)
    Next i

    'Adding additional tabs to tabstrip
    For i = 1 To ComboBox.Value - 1
        TabStrip1.Tabs.Add
    Next i
End Sub
```

The tab currently selected can be identified by using the `TabStrip1.Value` property. I think the change event is queued by the `TabStrip1.Value` changing.
You will have to manually clear out any values when the tab strip changes (or fill back in values they previously filled out but want to view again).

However, since you'd be determining which tab you're on by "index" (the `.value` property) you could create a 2d array (redim it to correct rows/columns based off combobox1's value) and use the tab "index" to store combobox values and retrieve existing values for when the user switches back to an existing tab.

And maybe consider "locking" the combobox1 so the value can't be changed by accident. This could be accomplished by having a variable initialized to, maybe -1, which gets set to the combobox value after they've started adding infor to the incidents. Or don't remove any tabstrip tabs, only add if the number is greater than the existing count. (If you want them to put in whatever value they'd like, maybe consider using a textbox?)